# Grep rsync output?

Tags: regex, grep

Running an rsync command produces output similar to this :

```
66256896  92%    4.51MB/s    0:00:01
```

How can I grep this output for just the percentage value ?
So anything {0-100}% so instead of showing the full output I only see the percentage ?

The command would be:

```
rsyncd -Pav server.com::files/remotefile.tar.gz localfile.tar.gz  | grep xxx
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use sed, this ugly thing works!

```
rsyncd -Pav server.com::files/remotefile.tar.gz localfile.tar.gz  | sed -e 's/%.*/%/; s/.* //'
```

It replaces `%` followed by the rest of the line with just `%` (thereby deleting everything after the percent), then replaces everything up to the space before the percentage also with nothing.

Comment: Thanks when I try this I just get the following each on a new line.
consider
remotefile.tar.gz
0%
bytes/sec
1.00

Comment: I think rsync maybe manipulates the cursor position which prevents sed doing its stuff :-(